# What Is The Output Of This Code, I Didn't Got Any Outputn Because My Computer Is Very Slow

Tags: python, algorithm

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal()
a = 2

for i in range(1, 64):
    a = a*a
print(a)
```

[image]

Comment: Your calculation has at least 3 mistakes.

Comment: The output of your program if it could run, would have around 10 quintillion digits.

Comment: There's squares with 8 and (what looks to be) 32 grains of rice in the image. The text suggests the sequence starts 1, 2, 4, 16. Your sequence starts 2, 4, 16, 256.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at the question in the image, what you're actually looking to do is sum the values, not just get the largest one.

Since:

`2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^n = 1 + 2 + ... + 2^n = 2^(n+1) - 1`

all the code you really need is:

```
print(pow(a,64) - 1)
```

Comment: The image says in "ONE, TWO FOUR, SIXTEEN ORDER".

Comment: @PaulHankin You're right - I'll change to the correct equation soon